# Is it possible to have indexes on non-materialized views?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, can I have an index on a non-materialized view?

I'm using a view in my application and it basically works well, but I'd like to speed up access to its data. I could switch to a materialized view, but I don't want to have to refresh it.

Comment: indexes on the original tables (or on functions of the original tables) can help. so long as the view is a subset of rows and not an aggregate.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## No

From https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1516969

> in postgres, views are essentially macros, thus there is no data to index

and

> A normal (non-materialized) view doesn't have any data of its own, it
> pulls it from one or more other tables on the fly during query
> execution. The execution of a view is kind of similar to a
> set-returning  function or a subquery, almost as if you'd substituted
> the view  definition into the original query.
>
> That means that the view will use any indexes on the original
> table(s),  but there isn't really even an opportunity to check for
> indexes on the  view its self because the view's definition is
> effectively substituted  into the query. If the view definition is
> complex enough that it does a  lot of work where indexes on the
> original table(s) don't help, that work  has to be done every time.

and

> What you *CAN* do is use triggers to maintain your own materialized
> views as regular tables, and have indexes on the tables you maintain
> using triggers. This is widely discussed on the mailing list and isn't
> hard to do, though it's tricky to make updates perform well with some
> kinds of materialized view query.